# Python mandatoryl arbitrary argument list *args

Tags: python, variadic-functions

is there any way to define a mandatory *args (arbitrary arguments) in a method of a class?

```
class foo():
 def __init__(self,*args):
      ....
```

Given this, you can create an object from the foo-class without any arguments x=foo(), i.e. its optional. Any ideas how to change it to a non-optional or "give me at least one arguments"-thing?

Another questions concerns the list unpacking with x=foo(*list) --> Is there a way to recognize the list as a list and unpack the list automatically, so that you don´t have to use the * in a function/method call?

Thx

Comment: It's a terrible idea to use `list` or any other builtin as a variable name

Comment: Nope, don´t get it. I want to use *args because of it´s list handling capabilities in a function which accepts one ore more arguments (and no "normal" arguments). In this case it would be nice to set the *args as mandatory, non-optional..(btw i dont use list as a variable name, that was just for the example)

Comment: :)another try:because *args is always optional?

Answer (score 4):

`*args` is meant to receive all arguments that are *not* already taken by normal arguments.

Usually if you need an argument to be mandatory, you just use a normal argument:

```
>>> def foo(arg, *rest):
...     print arg, rest
... 
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

If you think it is more elegant to gather all arguments in a tuple, you have to handle the error case yourself:

```
>>> def foo(*args):
...     if len(args) < 1:
...         raise TypeError('foo() takes at least 1 argument (%i given)' % len(args))
... 
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in foo
TypeError: foo() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

But as you can (or should) see, from the signature of that function it is not clear how many arguments to that function are mandatory to anyone who uses that function. You should either avoid this altogether or at least document it very well.

There are other problems as well: if you give on argument to `foo()` that is iterable (like a string), you will not get the intended result.

---

Responding to your comment below, your first approach was the right one: take a list.

```
def scrape(urls):
   for url in urls:
       do_something(url)
```

The caller simply has to pass a list with only one element: `scrape(['localhost'])`.

Even better would probably be to take only one URL and let the caller iterate over a list. In that case the caller could parallelize the operations if she ever wants to.

---

As to your second question<sup>1</sup>: either you function takes a list as an argument or it doesn't. Either it makes sense in your program to pass around lists or it doesn't.

I guess, I'm not entirely sure what you are asking there, but then again your whole question sounds like you found a shiny new tool and now you want to use it everywhere, regardless of whether it makes sense or not.

---

<sup>1</sup> please don't ask more than one question at once!

Comment: Thx!I´d like to use the *args in a shiny new tool which scrapes one or more urls (so it´ll be useless if you pass any url to it). Before using the *args, i simply iterated over a list inside the method, causing problems with a single url (i.e. a string) - but kindall mentioned the foo([list])-syntax in this case and it should work there.

Answer (score 2):

Either test the length of the resultant tuple, or put one or more normal arguments before it.

No.

Answer (score 0):

For "give me at least one argument," just check the `len()` of the tuple you receive and throw an exception if you don't get at least one. Here I am using the fact that empty tuples are "falsy" to do that implicitly:

```
def __init__(self, *args):
    if not args:
       raise TypeError("__init__ takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)")
```

For "auto-unpacking," you will also need to test for this and perform it yourself. One method might be:

```
if len(args) == 1 and not isinstance(args[0], basestring) and iter(args[0]):
    args = args[0]
```

The `iter()` will always be true, but if what you pass it is not iterable, it will raise an exception. If you want to provide a friendlier error message, you could catch it and raise something else.

Another alternative would be to write your method so that it recursively iterates over all elemets of `args` and all subcontainers within it; then it doesn't matter.

Or, you know, just have the caller pass in an iterable to begin with, and don't mess with `*args`. If the caller wants to pass in a single item, there is simple syntax to turn it into a list: `foo([item])`